# hadoop hdfs formatting gets error failed for Block pool

Tags: hadoop, formatting, hdfs

After formatting my hdfs, I get the following errors:

```
2015-05-28 21:41:57,544 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /usr/local/hadoop/dfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-e77ee39a-ab4a-4de1-b1a4-9d4da78b83e8; datanode clusterID = CID-6c250e90-658c-4363-9346-972330ff8bf9
2015-05-28 21:41:57,545 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting. 
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
    at.. org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:852)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
...blah...
SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at der-Inspiron-3521/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Here are the steps that I did:

```
 sbin/stop-dfs.sh
 hdfs namenode -format
 sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

For your information: my core-site.xml has the temp dir as follows:

```
<property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/usr/local/hadoop</value>
      <description>A base for other temporary directories.    
</description>
 </property>
```

and my hdfs-site.xml as the namenode and datanode as follows:

```
 <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>  
     <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/dfs/namenode</value>
  </property>



 <property> 
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/dfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
```

---

Update:
I have gotten a bit further with the issue but still I am getting the same type of error. I was able to run the `hdfs dfs -format` and change the version  **as advised**. After that I used the `hdfs dfs -ls and hdfs dfs -mkdir to create /user/der` wher der is my log in name. However when I ran the my
 pig file, I take mkDirs and chmod errors in my pig file.
 Here are the permissions for my datanode and namenode:

```
drwx------ 3 der  der  4096 May 29 08:13 datanode
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 May 28 11:34 name
drwxrwxr-x 3 der  der  4096 May 29 08:13 namenode
drwxrwxr-x 3 der  der  4096 May 29 08:13 namesecondary
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 28 11:46 ww
```

It seems datanode only has permissions for owner and group but not user.

Here is my pig script error:

```
2015-05-29 08:37:27,152 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:totalmiles.pig got an error while submitting 
ENOENT: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl
```

Here is my pig script:

```
records = LOAD '1987.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
        (Year, Month, DayofMonth, DayOfWeek, 
         DepTime, CRSDepTime, ArrTime, CRSArrTime, 
         UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,
         CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay, DepDelay, 
         Origin, Dest,  Distance:int, TaxIn, 
         TaxiOut, Cancelled,CancellationCode,  Diverted, 
         CarrierDelay, WeatherDelay, NASDelay, SecurityDelay,
         lateAircraftDelay);
milage_recs= GROUP records ALL;
tot_miles = FOREACH milage_recs GENERATE SUM(records.Distance);
STORE tot_miles INTO 'totalmiles4';
```

Update:
By the way I used chmod go+rw on datanode (after I stopped the namenode server and datanode server). That did not work as well.

---

Update May 30:
A bit more details.
 I changed the parent directory of the pig script in my pig script to this:

```
records = LOAD '/user/der/1987.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS
```

I have the same error. On the client side, here's the error. The only difference is that there is not hdfs:// prefix to the failed input read.

```
Failed to read data from "/user/der/1987.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/der/totalmiles4"
```

On the server side here is the namenode log just at the moment I get the invalid file request from my pig script. The log (using tail -f) scrolled. This indicates that the server is accepting request for the pig command.

```
          2015-05-30 07:01:28,140 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 127.0.0.1:50010 is added to 
        blk_1073741885_1061{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, 
    truncateBlock=null,
 primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-c84e0e37-2726-44da-af3e-67167c1010d1:NORMAL:127.0.0.1:50010|RBW]]}
     size 0

            2015-05-30 07:01:28,148 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile:
     /tmp/temp-11418443/tmp85697770/automaton-1.11-8.jar 
is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1939565577_1
```

I am just have to get the source code of the pig script and check the extact hdfs commands it issues. I think there is someone wrong with the hadoop hdfs services that I configured.

Answer (score 20):

> 2015-05-28 21:41:57,544 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /usr/local/hadoop/dfs/datanode: **namenode clusterID = CID-e77ee39a-ab4a-4de1-b1a4-9d4da78b83e8**; **datanode clusterID = CID-6c250e90-658c-4363-9346-972330ff8bf9**

Your **namenode and datanode cluster ID does not match**.

Open your `usr/local/hadoop/dfs/datanode/current/VERSION` file and change:

```
clusterID=CID-6c250e90-658c-4363-9346-972330ff8bf9
```

to

```
clusterID=CID-e77ee39a-ab4a-4de1-b1a4-9d4da78b83e8
```

> **NOTE:** Whenever you format your namenode, check the **VERSION** file of **namenode** and **datanode**. They both should have same
>   **clusterID** and **namespaceID**. Otherwise your datanode, won't start.

Comment: I got the formatting working, but I am still getting errors when I ran my pig script. Permissions log added to above question.

Comment: I did not see the namespaceID on the datanode. It is only the namenode that has the namespaceID, so I did not add any entries to the namenode.

Comment: Try to give full path for `1987.csv` like `/user/files/1987.csv`, if its in `/user/files/` folder of `HDFS`.

Comment: I have just tried. I updated my log above called Update May 30. I have to download the pig source and recompile it to take a look. I even tried a simple counter pig command and that did not work.

Comment: Another way to fix the problem would be to reformat the namenode and give it the ID used by the datanodes: ./hdfs namenode -format -clusterId CID-6c250e90-658c-4363-9346-972330ff8bf9

Answer (score 3):

The same problem happened to me. I deleted the contents of data directory and then ran hdfs datanode. This created the VERSION and other files inside the datanode directory. This solved my problem.